# converting nested json to csv dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

```
{"Interval":"OneMinute","Candles":[{"InstrumentId":7,"Candles":[{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03-17T03:44:00Z","Open":0.77329,"High":0.77335,"Low":0.77329,"Close":0.77329},{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03-17T03:43:00Z","Open":0.77325,"High":0.77332,"Low":0.77325,"Close":0.77329},{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03-17T03:42:00Z","Open":0.77333,"High":0.77333,"Low":0.77323,"Close":0.77325},{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03-17T03:41:00Z","Open":0.77335,"High":0.77338,"Low":0.77334,"Close":0.77334},{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03-17T03:40:00Z","Open":0.77330,"High":0.77336,"Low":0.77325,"Close":0.77335},{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03-17T03:39:00Z","Open":0.77335,"High":0.77336,"Low":0.77325,"Close":0.77330},{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03-17T03:38:00Z","Open":0.77330,"High":0.77336,"Low":0.77330,"Close":0.77336},{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03-17T03:37:00Z","Open":0.77331,"High":0.77335,"Low":0.77329,"Close":0.77330},{"InstrumentID":7,"FromDate":"2021-03
```

trying to convert this from json to datafram any help would  be appriciated

Comment: Your JSON is incomplete... Pandas can read json natively

Comment: What do expect the dataframe to look like?

Comment: try `pd.read_json`, plus need more information